# To make my art or to work for the readers? (For a profits-intended work)

Tags: creative-writing

I want to make my art, to express with no limits. However, I also need to profit with it. If I sell my art purely, the readers *might* not understand, like or be interested in it, and thus resulting in low sales, although I would like very much what I've done. If I want more sales, I would have to water it down with what the public likes/expects, thus my "art" wouldn't be "pure" (original), but a mainstreamy production. Thus, if I need to put only what the public likes and avoid putting what the public might dislike, I would simply be indirectly working *for* the readers, always having to please *them*, or else...

But by "to make my art" I do not in any way mean "to ignore quality standards", it's exactly the opposite; it actually refers to content: it's too nichey, and everyone knows that nichey = low sales, compared to the mainstream.

So I feel divided: one side of me *really* wants to be free to make my nichey art, while the other side *needs* the profits (to be used in another project) that this nichey art is not much likely to give and thus needing to change it.

How do I get out of this?

Comment: I'm an amateur and will only suggest a small tip. Might be idiotic, so I apologize for it. Can't you combine the two? You could create 5 original artworks and 1 mainstream art, then see what happens. I don't know if you've already put your art out there or not, but people need to see it first and everyone has different tastes. Your original art might sell more than the 1 mainstream you painted. Combining the two will get your original art visibility if people search for the mainstream one. You can't just create what people want 'cause you'll hate it and end with an artist's block that way.

Comment: The "Director's Cut" approach can always be tried, but may be received differently, depending on the medium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a false dichotomy. Art is a form of communication. It fails if it does not communicate. We hear a lot of talk about "expressing yourself" but that is hollow unless you are expressing yourself to someone. We are social animals. We strive to make ourselves understood to others. Good art is art that communicates, that is not only expressed but received. Art that is not received is bad art. (There is a lot of bad art in the world.)

This does not mean that everything that communicates is art, of course. Nor does it mean that the best art appeals to the widest audience. But good art appeals to a substantial audience, at least, an audience large enough to live on.

Of course, not all art is appreciated in its day. Sometimes even the most effective art is stymied by the whims of fashion and its greatness is only recognized after the artist is no longer around to make a living on it. But we should not exaggerate this. Most good art is appreciated in its day. Most good artists find a way to express their vision within the limits of the current taste. That is part of the craft of art.

Art is the expression of profound vision. Most of us do not have a profound vision to express. But those who do have a profound vision need to learn a lot of craft in order to express that vision successfully.

If you do have a profound vision, it is likely that it will express itself in all the work you do. Not certain, I suppose. You could work in an utterly cynical manner to appeal to the popular taste without any trace of vision. But if you have the craft to appeal to the popular taste and the vision to produce art, you should have the tools to create art that is popular enough to make a living from. If you have the vision but not the craft, you can only produce failed art. If you have the craft and not the vision, you can at least produce effective entertainment.

Most of us, of course, don't have either the vision or the craft to pull that off. But my inclination is that if you have the vision, it will come through in any honest work you do. Therefore, focus on the craft, aim to write popular stories, and let the vision come through if it is there.

EDIT: Bye the bye, boarding school for wizards was a very niche concept, and at least 50 years out of date (who goes to boarding school any more?). And then it wasn't.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a common issue for any kind of artist.**

I'm making this example in the world of music because I still have a lot more experience in that world, but **I assume this can be translated to the world of books fairly easily.** Take this made-up musician:

John J. Johnsson wants to make Arabic-cultured-melodic-inspired EDM-techno-beats with heavy-metal-inspired growling and screaming.

John probably starts out producing the kind of music he loves and wants others to like and admire him for.

John could be **extremely lucky** and strike "viral gold" with one of his tracks/songs and gain sudden 'pop-culture-appeal' but it is unlikely - otherwise, we'd have viral tracks of new genres every day.

What John will most likely experience is, that a few people will like his music (if he dares to post/release it anywhere) and a lot of people will not be interested.

**THIS HAPPENS TO ALMOST ANY KIND OF ARTIST** and most likely to 99 out of 100 new 'experimental' or 'niche' musicians/artists in general.

This will, of course, be extremely frustrating. John wants to make **his** music and wishes that a lot of people naturally wanted his music.

What many musicians then do is, "make their music more pop-friendly". 
**This is painful** for anyone who doesn't by default make "pop-music", but in order to gain an audience, **it may be necessary**.

Some musicians produce one "pop" song, others multiple "pop" albums, before 'suddenly' changing their style/genre and surprising almost all of their fans so far. Some stay in their personal pop-genre for good. Some people make completely different music within another genre altogether, others just tone down the "niche-elements".

At some point along the road of someone's career, they have to decide to "go pop" or keep working hard on their own art and hope for the fan-base to grow naturally.

If that someone does "go pop", they then have to decide at some other point if they can "go un-pop", and how...

In the end, **the choice is yours** and it's not an easy choice. 
Whether or not I can support you as a future reader, I can't say, but I can certainly say this: I support you in your struggle to decide, and hope you are closer to your dream scenario in the not too distant future.

I assume that communicating/collaborating with other people within the same or a similar genre/niche can help you in your work, but in the end, your work is your work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth playing with pseudonyms, or slight variations on the name by which you want to be known (Michael Marshall Smith, Iain M. Banks, Richard Bachman). You could use the variation to differentiate the styles.

The populist consumers might never know, but your niche audience will love the feeling they're in on a secret.